# How to find out where a macro is defined?

Tags: macros, tex-core

Using `\@ifdefined` (in LaTeX), we can check whether a command is defined.

Using `\meaning`, we can get the definition of a command.

Can we also get information about *where* a command was defined? For example, in terms of the source file and line number? Does TeX even keep track of this information?

We can `grep` through source files, but with constructs like `\csname`, there's no guarantee that the definition will show up.

Comment: On the 'does TeX keep a track' part of the question: no.

Comment: @Joseph: Although it is technically feasible to change the underlying engine to do this.  I think that in Luatex, you can apply the techniques in http://www.ntg.nl/maps/35/05.pdf to write a meta-interpreter for Tex that evaluates tokens in the usual way but wraps code around `\def`s to log them appropriately to a Lua table.  You could then rebuild Latex, tex4ht-style, so that all macros have this information.  I'm curious to see if I can do this: I've not really got the hang of token processing in Luatex yet, and it seems like a suitable challenge.

Comment: @Charles: I believe that it might be possible to do that in TeX only. Redefine `\def`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\gdef` starting with `\def\dummy{}` to get the prefixes; then grab function and argument with `\grabfargs` defined as `\def\grabfargs#1#2#{...}`; then the replacement text and do the definition, logging whatever you want. Problems: this loses `\afterassignment` (we can replace by storing with `\let`), and treats `\global\def` as `\def`, so we need to redefine `\global` as something like `\@globaltrue\afterassignment\afterglobal` with suitable definitions. Not infeasible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Oh, I find a much better way to do this, also with help of `filehook` (the code is somewhat tricky):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filehook,currfile}
\newwrite\finder
\immediate\openout\finder=\jobname.fnd

\def\searchmacro#1{
  \AtBeginOfFiles{%
    \ifdefined#1
      \expandafter\def\csname \currfilename:found\endcsname{}%
    \fi}
  \AtEndOfFiles{%
    \ifdefined#1
      \unless\ifcsname \currfilename:found\endcsname
        \immediate\write\finder{found in '\currfilename'}%
    \fi\fi}}

\searchmacro\url

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
dummy
\end{document}
```

After compiling, we will get

```
found in 'url.sty'
found in 'hyperref.sty'
```

in `\jobname.fnd`. That is to say, `\url` is defined in `url.sty`, which is inputed by `hyperref.sty`.

Comment: I'm sorry this answer is a bit late.

Comment: I'd still call this quite quick.

Comment: That's beautiful!

Comment: @Leo: Could one turn this into a function with one argument?

Comment: @Faheem: Yes. But it would be a little more complex, if you want to search several macros at one time. It seems the new version of `filehook` makes the code not workable, I'll fix it later.

Comment: fixed for `filehook` v0.4 or later.

Comment: Leo: Thanks. Appreciate it. So the usage is \searchmacro followed by the macro?

Comment: Yes, it is. But only one macro.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm planning to put something like this into my [latexdef](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) tool.

Comment: @Leo: The code will also report packages which load the package which defines the macro. Here both `url` and `hyperref` define `\url`, but if you would load `url` inside another package it would also be listed. This is because at the beginning of that package `\url` isn't yet defined but at the end after `url` is loaded it is. Also if `url` is loaded before `hyperref` the latter isn't listed any longer. Anyway I updated `latexdef` to use `filehook` like you suggested. It will report the package which first defines the given macro(s). Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 13):

Leo's answer using `filehook` and `currfile` brought me to the idea to include these technique into v1.2 of the [`latexdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) tool (Perl script). It will report the first package which defines the given macros.

#### Example:

Shows the definition and the location of \relax, \toprule and \includegraphics after loading the 'booktabs' and 'graphicx' packages:

```
# latexdef -p booktabs -p graphicx -f relax toprule includegraphics
\relax is defined by (La)TeX.

\relax:
\relax

\toprule first defined in "booktabs.sty".

\toprule:
macro:->\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\abovetopsep \global \@belowrulesep =\belowrulesep \global \@thisruleclass =\@ne \@ifnextchar [{\@BTrule }{\@BTrule [\heavyrulewidth ]}

\includegraphics first defined in "graphics.sty".

\includegraphics:
macro:->\@ifstar {\Gin@cliptrue \Gin@i }{\Gin@clipfalse \Gin@i }
```

Answer (score 10):

How about use `trace` package and seek the macro in the log file? `filehook` package can help us to add the file name tag into the log file. For example:

```
\usepackage[logonly]{trace}
\usepackage{filehook}
\AtBeginOfFiles{\wlog{INFILE:<#1>}}
\AtEndOfFiles{\wlog{OUTFILE:<#1>}}
\traceon
\usepackage{amsmath}
\traceoff
```

Then we can find that `\subarray` is defined in `amsmath.sty`. Since

```
{into \subarray=\long macro:#1->\vcenter \bgroup \Let@ \restore@math@cr \ETC.}
```

appears after `INFILE:<amsmath.sty>`, but does not after `OUTFILE:<amsmath.sty>`.
This needs some manual work, I use vim to search the patterns.

Warning: this may produce an extreamly *huge* log file. Most of time, I think a simple bisection method can work for this.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! "Huge" in this case was only 80 MB, nothing my computer couldn't handle.

Comment: I find a better answer (see below). Since this one has been accepted, it remains unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

- If you know which classes/packages to search in, then the `latexdef` tool is a good choice.
- If you don't know, and your document loads lots of packages and/or is divided into subfiles that define macros, then Leo's `currfile` solution is helpful.

However, those solutions will only find the first definition, which may not help if the macro you are looking for is redefined with a different definition later.

Here I build on Leo's solution to report online (as in, on the terminal and pausing execution with `\show`, rather than saving to another file) each file in which the definition of your target macro(s) gets changed, wrapped in a package `reportmacrodefn.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{reportmacrodefn}

\RequirePackage{currfile}

\def\reportmacrodefn#1{%
    \ifdefined #1
        \edef\foundmacrodefn{^^J^^J\space'\string #1' is already defined^^J\space\space\space\space (with meaning \meaning #1),^^J\space\space\space\space(i.e. it is defined before executing the '\string\reportmacrodefn' line, possibly earlier in the document, in the format file or as a primitive.)^^J\space\space\space\space Will look for re-definitions}%
        \show\foundmacrodefn
    \else
        \typeout{** Looking for definitions of \string #1...}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\let\csname macrodefn\string #1\endcsname #1%
    \AtBeginOfFiles{%
        \expandafter\let\csname\currfilename/ macrodefn\string #1\endcsname #1%
    }%
    \AtEndOfFiles{%
        \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\let\expandafter\reportmacrodefntmp\csname\currfilename/ macrodefn\string #1\endcsname% avoid \relax side-effect of \csname...\endcsname
        \unless\ifx\reportmacrodefntmp #1% check if the macro has changed within file \currfilename
            \begingroup\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\let\expandafter\reportmacrodefntmpreported\csname macrodefn\string #1\endcsname
            \unless\ifx\reportmacrodefntmpreported #1%check if the macro has changed since the last time we reported it
                % don't report a line number as this only gets executed at the end of the input file so would be useless and misleading
                \edef\foundmacrodefn{^^J^^J\space'\string #1' changed^^J\space\space\space\space in '\currfilename' (file stack: \currfiledumpstack), ^^J\space\space\space\space was \meaning\reportmacrodefntmp^^J\space\space\space\space now \meaning #1}%
                \show\foundmacrodefn
                \expandafter\let\csname macrodefn\string #1\endcsname #1%
            \fi
        \fi
    }}

% currfile doesn't provide a friendly way to dump the stack, so here's one:
\ifcurrfile@abspath
\newcommand*\currfiledumpstack{%
  \expandafter\currfile@dumpstack\currfile@stack\stopquark\stopquark\stopquark\stopquark
}
\def\currfile@dumpstack#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifx#1\stopquark\@empty
  \else
  {#2\ifx\empty#3\empty\else.#3\fi}%
  \expandafter\currfile@dumpstack
  \fi
}
\else
\newcommand*\currfiledumpstack{%
  \expandafter\currfile@dumpstack\currfile@stack\stopquark\stopquark\stopquark
}
\def\currfile@dumpstack#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\stopquark\@empty
  \else
  {#2\ifx\empty#3\empty\else.#3\fi}%
  \expandafter\currfile@dumpstack
  \fi
}
\fi
```

Here's a test document to illustrate how to use the package (I called it `reportmacrodefntest.tex`):

```
\RequirePackage{reportmacrodefn}
\reportmacrodefn\[
\reportmacrodefn\text

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
See the terminal output during compilation, or the log file.
\end{document}
```

And the relevant output here is:

```
 '\[' is already defined
    (with meaning macro:->\relax \ifmmode \@badmath \else \ifvmode \nointerlineskip \makebox [.6\linewidth ]{}\fi $$\fi ),
    (i.e. it is defined before executing the '\reportmacrodefn' line, possibly earlier in the document, in the format file or as a primitive.)
    Will look for re-definitions.

 '\[' changed
    in 'fixltx2e.sty' (file stack: {reportmacrodefntest.tex}{}), 
    was macro:->\relax \ifmmode \@badmath \else \ifvmode \nointerlineskip \makebox [.6\linewidth ]{}\fi $$\fi 
    now macro:->\x@protect \[\protect \[  .

 '\text' changed
    in 'amstext.sty' (file stack: {amsmath.sty}{reportmacrodefntest.tex}{}), 
    was undefined
    now macro:->\protect \text  .
```

A couple of features of this solution that are worthy of note:

- Both `fixltx2e` and `amsmath` provide the same (one-level) definition of `\[`, and only the first one is reported.
- The `\text` macro is defined in `amstext.sty`, which was loaded by `amsmath`, and the definition is only reported once in the correct file, and the file stack is summarised too.

Of course, one still has to resort to `grep` or other approaches to find out *where* in the named file(s) the definition(s) are.

If the definition you are looking for is in the format file, then you should look in `latex.ltx` etc as suggested by Herbert, and the `--source` option to `latexdef` may be helpful.

Finally, this doesn't help if you're looking for something defined by the reporting code!

Answer (score 3):

*All* basic LaTeX commands are defined in files which are part of the base directory, which is at `$TEXMF/tex/latex/base`. If a command isn't found there, it is a so called primitive of TeX or defined in one of the additional loaded packages. 
The main basic files are `latex.ltx`and `fontmath.ltx`